# Database is connecting from SQLyog, but not from nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am able to connect database from SQLyog, but when connecting from Node.js getting following error:

**Database IP : 10.0.0.200**

```
Error when connecting to db: { Error: ER_DBACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'myuser'@'10.0.0.100' to database 'db_new'
at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:52:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:103:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:103:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:23)
    at Connection.connect (\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:130:18)
    at Timeout.handleDisconnect [as _onTimeout] (\techdoc-connection.js:25:16)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
  code: 'ER_DBACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1044,
  sqlMessage: 'Access denied for user \'myuser\'@\'10.0.0.100\' to database \'db_new\'',
  sqlState: '42000',
  fatal: true }
```

Code to connect to DB is as follows,

```
connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: settings.dbhost,
    user: settings.user,
    password: settings.password,
    database: settings.database
});
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Does IP `10.0.0.100` have access to `10.0.0.200`? Are you able to ping or telnet from `10.0.0.100` to `10.0.0.200`?

Comment: have you check this link https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/591 try to solve your issues ....

Comment: @Furqan Misarwala Did you checked that the user is GRANTED all privileges???

Comment: @AniketV : Yes I am able to ping.

Comment: @SyedAyeshaBebe: I have checked it.

Comment: @Subburaj: Yes, I have checked, It was not granted all privileges.
After granting all privileges, it has been fixed, Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Related: [Github issue on mysqljs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/591)

When encountering this issue, one common problem is that the user isn't being GRANTED with all the privileges. To grant with all the privileges, you may execute an SQL command as mysql suggests,

```
mysql> show grants;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for RollingRidge@%                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'RollingRidge'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*REDACTED'                                 |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `rollingridge`.* TO 'RollingRidge'@'%'                                              |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Hope this helps.